# certificaterevocationlist: requires ;binary transfer

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I have been trying to add a certificateRevocationList to an LDAP object of object class type "cRLDistributionPoint". For this puropse, I am using phpldapadmin to import an LDIF file which has following data:

```
dn: cn=Mandeep,dc=ec2,dc=internal
changetype: modify
add: certificateRevocationList;binary
certificateRevocationList;binary: MIIC1DCBvQIBATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBaMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UE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\nXKtHZLuqEDo=
```

This always results in an error and logs(slapd) suggests the below error:
"certificaterevocationlist: requires ;binary transfer"
I have an Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS machine which has slapd version 2.4.49 installed.

I am not sure where am I going wrong. I am already using the certificateRevocationList attribute as a binary transfer (as the rfc4523 says). Could someone help out ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a double colon `::` as a delimiter so that the value can be parsed properly, that is in this case, as a base64 representation of a binary value :

```
certificateRevocationList;binary:: <base64_str>
```

According to LDIF specifications / RFC 2849 :

- `:` specifies that the value is a string.
- `::` specifies that the value is the base 64 encoded string representation of a binary value, or a UTF-8 string that contains multi-byte characters.
- `:<` specifies that the value is to be read from a file URL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I even tried that. Did not work. I get the same error.